# Confusion over using of UnitOfWork in Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It's a week I have been dealing with Repository pattern, somehow I have implemented something, a generic repository:

```
private CentralEntities db = null;
private DbSet<T> table = null;

public RepositoryTest() 
{
    this.db = new CentralEntities();
    table = db.Set<T>();
}

public RepositoryTest(CentralEntities db)
{

    this.db = db;
    table = db.Set<T>();
}
public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll()
{           
    return table.Take(10).ToList();
}
```

Here is my IRepository:

```
public  interface IRepositoryTest<T> where T:class
{
    IEnumerable<T> SelectAll();
}
```

Here in my Controller I implemented like the following and it works:

```
public class DashbrdController : Controller
{

    IRepositoryTest<Event> _repository = null;

    public DashbrdController(IRepositoryTest<Event> _repository)
    {
        this._repository = _repository;
    }

    public DashbrdController()
    {
       this._repository = new RepositoryTest<Event>();
    }

    public ActionResult DashBrd()
    {
        var rslt= _repository.SelectAll().Take(10); 
        return View(rslt);

    }
}
```

First I do not how to implement Iunitofwork and UnitOfWork, and second apart from creating a single gate for update or insert, whats the usage of UnitOfWork? what kind of problem can it solve in the above example?

Comment: Why do you think you need unit of work pattern?

Comment: Perhaps you should just stick to using your DbContext (CentralEntities), which is _both_ a repository for each Entity type _and_ represents a UnitOfWork.

Comment: @trailmax im not sure,im confused

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft you mean i should forget the pattern?

Comment: You most likely should. Applying Unit of Work / Repository around Entity Framework is, in most cases, a bad idea. You should have a very good understanding of both patterns for that to be actually useful and not a maintenance nightmare

Comment: The EF DbContext implements the idea of a Repository with DbSet<T>, and the idea of a UnitOfWork with the Change Tracker and its transaction support.  Hiding those behind a custom layer of Repository and UnitOfWork abstractions is tricky, probably useless, and possibly harmful.  It's certainly not generally recommended, and definitely not for beginners.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft so i thought its a good idea to follow,having separated these layeres ,for testing,or for example dependency injection,...now in my controller,i instantiated my model,i use the LINQ also there in my controller i see now my controller is becoming biger and messy,so i thought these patterns can make it manageable

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the section below for detail understanding of UOW and Repository:

1) You create Generic Repository (The base of all the data source):

> public class GenericRepository : IGenericRepository where T :
>   class
>
> ```
> {
>     protected DbContext _entities;
>     protected readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;
>
>     public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
>     {
>         _entities = context;
>         _dbset = context.Set<T>();
>     }
>
>
>     public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
>     {
>         return _dbset.AsEnumerable();
>     }
>
>     public IEnumerable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
>     {
>         IEnumerable<T> query = _dbset.Where(predicate).AsEnumerable();
>         return query;
>     }
>
>     public virtual T GetSingle(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
>     {
>         T query = _dbset.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
>         return query;
>     }
>
>     public virtual void Add(T entity)
>     {
>         _dbset.Add(entity);
>     }
>
>
>     public virtual void Delete(T entity)
>     {
>         _dbset.Remove(entity);            
>     }
>
>     public virtual void Edit(T entity)
>     {
>         _entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
>
>
>     }
>     public virtual void Attach(T entity)
>     {            
>         _dbset.Attach(entity);
>     }
>
>     public virtual void Save()
>     {
>         _entities.SaveChanges();
>     }
> }
> ```

2) Then you create a Unit Of Work (Generic that adds the instance of Repository)

> public sealed class GenericUnitOfWork : IGenericUnitOfWork, IDisposable

```
{
    private ApplicationDbContext entities = null;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;


    public GenericUnitOfWork()
    {
        entities = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }


    public Dictionary<Type, object> repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public IGenericRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)) == true)
        {
            return repositories[typeof(T)] as IGenericRepository<T>;
        }
        IGenericRepository<T> repo = new GenericRepository<T>(entities);
        repositories.Add(typeof(T), repo);
        return repo;
    }


    public int Commit()
    {
        return entities.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                entities.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }



}
```

3) Then you call UnitOfWork from your controller, that creates instance of Repository in Generic Form

> ```
>  public class DashbrdController : Controller
>     {
>         private GenericUnitOfWork uow = null;
>
>         public DashbrdController()
>         {
>             uow = new GenericUnitOfWork();
>         }
>
>         public ActionResult DashBrd()
>         {
>             var rslt = uow.Repository<Event>().GetAll().ToList();
>             return View(rslt);
>
>         }
>     }
> ```

The unit of work class coordinates the work of multiple repositories by **creating a single database context class** shared by all of them.

For a specific user action (say adding a event), **all the transactions like insert/update/delete and so on are done in one single transaction, rather then doing multiple database transactions**. This means, one unit of work here involves insert/update/delete operations, all in one single transaction.

Please make the interfaces with the implementation classes provided above. Let me know if problem occurs in that.

Hope if helps.